# rails link_to helper with multiple html options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following link_to in rails

```
<%= link_to 'Import now', action: :import_ads, status: 1, remote: true,class: 'hidden-link', %>
```

The above link render as

```
<a href="/import_ads?class=hidden-link&status=1" data-remote="true">Import now</a>
```

Why class name is becoming as querystring. How to solve it

Answer (score 1):

This is a time where not including parens/braces can hurt you.  try this

```
<%= link_to 'Import now', {action: :import_ads, status: 1},  { remote: true, class: 'hidden-link'} %>
```

Which should pass class and remote as html_options   ( `link_to(body, url, html_options = {}`) )

Comment: Could also move `status: 1` to the end.

Comment: above link throwing syntax error yntax error, `unexpected ')', expecting =>` I tried some possibilities but I could not solve it

Comment: try now  had an extra `,` at the end

Comment: Hmm normally I don't use something action/status and normally have a named route in there for the url, the url options are just passed to url_for...

Comment: try this version to group the import_ads/ status into the options hash, which should be passed to url_for to generate the url